# UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler not working in Springboot 3.x but work fine in 2.x - thus login not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-3

I have a wonderfully working SpringBoot2 application with a

- UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - to perform a login with 3 fields (tenant, user, password)
- SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler - to perform actions upon logout

When I tried to migrate to SpringBoot3 I did not manage to configure it properly to make it work.

I've extracted the basic app into
https://github.com/ottlinger/sb3-filter-problem/
and provided a SB2 and SB3 submodule.

Any help is greatly appreciated and further information and quick links can be found in
https://github.com/ottlinger/sb3-filter-problem/blob/main/README.md

The SB3 login does not work at all, it seems as if the filter collides with the regular login/authentication workflow.

The working SB2 application shows how things are properly configured in SB2, but do not work in SB3.

In order to play with the two applications they can be started via Maven.

Comment: You have 2 totally different configurations. Why did you come up with the `SB3DSL` stuff? That is needed for nothing, nor is it even being used. Just convert your configuration from SB2 to the new SB3 configuration, ie. remove the extends and use a method that creates a `SecurityFilterBean`. Which means basically an almost 1-on-1 copy of what you had. Also there is a flaw in both your configuration as you can only add filters before known filters, there is no `LoginTenantAuthenticationFilter.class`. You want to register it before the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` or `BasicAuthFilter`.

Comment: @M.Deinum the hint is taken from 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10822#issuecomment-1396795976
as the SB2 way does not work due to the deprecation of the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Comment: Correct but it doesn't require a seperate configuration, you could just convert it, almost as it, to return a `SecurityFilterBean`. Return it from the method and add `@Bean`. You would only need to call `http.build()`. You probably get some deprecation warnings for the configuration methods but that would be it. You would also need to provide the correct filter position (which you didn't), so I'm actual surprised it worked on SB2.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm not sure if you are looking at the correct subfolder - the SB3 part is:
https://github.com/ottlinger/sb3-filter-problem/blob/main/sb3/src/main/java/de/aikiit/prototype3/configuration/AuthenticationConfiguration.java#L50

As the filter needs the authenticationManager to pass on the authentication the  SB3DSL class is a workaround for that.

Comment: Yes I'm looking at that I'm not looking at something else (although I pefer code in your question instead of having to click through a full repository. You can just wire the `AuthenticationManager` into the filter through a parameter (or make the filter an `@Component`). But still your filter ordering is off/wrong and the configuration isn't the same.

Comment: I suspect it worked in SB2 because it was an `@Bean` and it was registered twice (once as a regular filter and once as part of Spring Security). You are now lacking the first (as it should) and now you notice the actual error (the ordering of the filters).

Comment: One of the main differences seems to be that in SB3 you cannot wire in the authenticationManager anymore - I just tried that but the bean is not found.

Comment: You have to expose it as a bean (which is in the documentation as well). But as said I'm surprised it works in SB2 and it probably works due to my previous comment.

Comment: I checked the logs for the order of the filters - they seem to be in similar order in SB2 and SB3 (cannot post the log entry as it is too long). Can you point me to the docs you are referring to? @M.Deinum

Comment: I was referring to the actual Spring Security documentation, the migration guides from 5.7, 5.8 and 6.0 have the information you need. I was wrong about your filter being a bean (which it ideally should be imho). It will also walk the tree so eventually will arrive at `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` for the order.

Comment: Don't configure the `login()` as that is what your filter is doing.

Comment: Thanks for your guess - following the docs at https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html I have changed the configuration to use the lambda syntax, but did not find any reference about a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and SB3.
Do you have a reference concerning the order of filters & SB3? @M.Deinum

Comment: The filter ordering hasn't changed. It works on my machine if I just comment the login page stuff (as that probably interferes with your registration). I did use the new `with` instead of `apply` syntax.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand what you mean on how the filter does the configuration ..... replacing the way the filter is initialized with

```lang-java
  http.with(Sb3CustomDsl.create(), Customizer.withDefaults());
```

does not help, as the default spring-security login page is shown instead if I remove the formLogin-lambda:

```lang-java
  http.formLogin((formLogin) ->
            formLogin
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .failureHandler(failureHandler())
                    .permitAll()
    );
```

Comment: It works for me. `/login` is the default url so you aren't really configuring anything extra with this. I also wonder why are you on Spring Boot 3.2 which is still in development?

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work for me - if I remove the http.formLogin block all I get is an empty white page. Manually calling /login yields a login, but after I hit submit nothing happens.
Can you fork the repo and apply the changes in the sb3 submodule?
Thanks in advance for any help as documentation only yields pages that configure formLogin for SpringBoot2 et.al.

Comment: For anyone considering spending time trying to answer this, please note that it has also been reported as a [Spring Security issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/13620).

Comment: @M.Deinum in case you made the sb3-app work I'm happy to accept any pull requests. Trying to report an issue did not yet generate any feedback, neither in spring-boot nor in spring-security.

Comment: Well I'm not surprised as it is more a question as an issue. I don't recall anymore what I changed (i do recall stripping the filter making it simpler and removing the login page).

Comment: Problem is still remaining and is still unsolved - other articles that try to offer solutions to the same problem do not work with SB 3.2 as the authentication manager cannot be wired in.
Trying to change the order of the filters does not work as well. Filter itself is loaded, but the login does not happen properly.